# Can I get the include path of the js file - within the js file?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible for a js function to figure out the file path of its code ? At runtime.

Ex. 
`<html><head><script src="/js/version-3.2.1/myfile.js" /><head>...</html>`

/js/version-3.2.1/myfile.js

```js
const scriptPath = '/js/version-3.2.1/myfile.js' // how do I get this dynamically?: 
const version = scriptPath.split('-')[1].split('/')[0];
console.log("the version is " + version)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript):

> The `Document.currentScript` property returns the `<script>` element whose script is currently being processed and isn't a JavaScript module. (For modules use `import.meta` instead.)
>
> It's important to note that this will not reference the `<script>` element if the code in the script is being called as a callback or event handler; it will only reference the element while it's initially being processed.

```
const scriptPath = document.currentScript.src
// or
const scriptPath = document.currentScript.getAttribute('src')
```